# HBase - difference between drop table and delete table?

Tags: hbase

I am learning HBase shell commands and getting confused by drop and delete table.

Could anyone comment on the difference between dropping a table and deleting a table?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference. I speculate that the reason for the two names is because [HBaseAdmin](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html) was created first, and it used "delete". Then when the shell was created folks realized that `drop table tablename` is the standard way to get rid of a table.*

But I confirm (regardless of the speculation into its origin) that they are the same by looking at the [HBase Admin source file admin.rb](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/trunk/hbase-server/src/main/ruby/hbase/admin.rb):

```
# Drops a table
def drop(table_name)
  tableExists(table_name)
  raise ArgumentError, "Table #{table_name} is enabled. Disable it first.'" if enabled?(table_name)
  @admin.deleteTable(table_name)
end
```

*But to be precise... they did not go with `drop table tablename` but rather `drop 'tablename'` in the HBase shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic difference :

- delete is used to delete a particular cell in a table and hence you can't run delete on a table directly and expect it to be deleted.
- drop will drop the entire table without any reference to cell without disabling a table first.

From the image - you can see that hbase suggested that delete should be accompanied with cell reference as well and drop simply dropped the table and there is no table after that command.

[image: HBase delete/drop difference]

Answer (score 0):

Just for some addition. In other to delete a table via hbase shell or java api. first you have to disable table then drop. Otherwise table could not be deleted.